# U.K. company has deducted tax

Tags: invoices

My wife invoiced a university for some work she did.

She’s just had the paperwork back and they have taken tax from the total amount that she invoiced for. Is this right? I have never heard of this happening before. Normally people pay invoices in full, and we deal with the tax as part of our accounting.

Is this right that they did this?

EDIT: rather than as a supplier they seem to have set her up as an employee with no start date then issued a p45. WTAF??!

Comment: Did she have a contract in place that explained how she was going to be paid?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what other advice would be useful than suggesting that you contact whoever issues their invoices (presumably a Finance Department) and explaining that;

- **You're not sure what they've done** (or why)
- **Can they please undo it *immediately*** 

  and
- **make a payment into your bank account like they should have done in the first place**.

You may need to refer them to your invoice or whatever contract you (hopefully) have in place with whoever hired you in the first place.